# Android: Unable to Prevent buttons from increasing size and overlapping with other buttons

Tags: android, button

I am new to Android Programming, what I am trying to do in this Android Application is to create a xml page filled with buttons.

When I click the button, the button would change to light green color and when I click it again, it would change to light grey

The error: I am getting is when I click the button, it increases in size and overlaps with the other buttons, please help me out here, it is not user friendly in this case

attached below is the code:

lockerbooking.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/sis"
     />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/solButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/sol" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/soe" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

makeBooking.java

```
public class makeBooking extends Activity {

Button sisButton;
Button solButton;
Button soeButton;
Button sobButton;



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the message from the intent
    setContentView(R.layout.lockerbookpage);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Initialize TextViews
    sisButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sisButton);
    solButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.solButton);
    soeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soeButton);
    sobButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sobButton);
       }
   public OnClickListener solButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){


    boolean flag = true;

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(flag){
            solButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        else{
            solButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        flag=!flag;
    }

};
```

...The code goes on

Please help me out here, I am eager to learn

Comment: The code you have posted shouldn't change the size of the buttons. Are you also changing the text in the buttons somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid overlapping of buttons, use fixed width and height for buttons:
change this:

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to some this like this:

```
 android:layout_width="100dp" //what ever size suits your layout
 android:layout_height="50dp" //fixing this,will not overlap the buttons
```